# Django UpdateView is not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

My question is when I use an `UpdateView`, it doesn't update the record. Besides this it also doesn't give any error.

When I debug code, the `form_valid()` function is not called after the HTTP POST request. But my form class (`AdvertisementDetailForm`) is correctly working. I couldn't find what I'm doing wrong.

Console outputs like that:

> GET
>   /advertisement/publish/adv1_3ad5f56a-d99d-4ed4-b878-1327b9fa1bf8/1/
>   HTTP/1.1
>   POST
>   /advertisement/publish/adv1_3ad5f56a-d99d-4ed4-b878-1327b9fa1bf8/1/
>   HTTP/1.1

1st App views.py:

```
class PublishAdvertisement(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    login_url = '/'
    redirect_field_name = '/'
    model = AdvSummary
    form_class = AdvertisementDetailForm
    template_name = 'advertisement/publish_advertisement.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('brand:brand_home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        obj = get_object_or_404(AdvSummary, pk=pk)
        obj.advertisement_image = form.cleaned_data['advertisement_image']
        obj.adv_max_follower = self.request.POST['adv_max_follower']
        obj.adv_min_follower = self.request.POST['adv_min_follower']
        obj.adv_desc = self.request.POST['adv_desc']
        selected_categories = Category.objects.filter(pk__in=self.request.POST.getlist('categories'))
        obj.categories.add(*[cat for cat in selected_categories])
        obj.publish_date = timezone.now()
        obj.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('publish/<slug:slug_name>/<int:pk>/',
         views.PublishAdvertisement.as_view(), name='publish'),
    path('delete/<slug:slug_name>/<int:pk>/',
         views.DeleteAdvertisement.as_view(), name='delete'),
]
```

2nd app views.py:

```
class BrandHomePage(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.View):
    login_url = '/'
    redirect_field_name = '/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = CreateAdvertisement.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = PublishedAdvertisementList.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.BrandHomePage.as_view(), name='brand_home'),
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Solution:**

I've figured it out problem's reason when I added form_invalid() function just like that:

```
def form_invalid(self, form):
    print("form is invalid")
    return HttpResponse("form is invalid.. this is just an HttpResponse object")
```

And I've find out error in forms.py

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    obj = get_object_or_404(AdvSummary, pk=pk)
```

Check here that you are getting object or not.